# Error al trabajar con libreria de streamlit y pydeck, python3.8

Tags: python, python-3.8

Estoy aprendiendo de la libreria streamlit, pero al implementar el ejemplo de la documentación [streamlit.pydeck_chart](https://docs.streamlit.io/en/stable/api.html?#streamlit.pydeck_chart) pero al implementarlo me tira un error como se presenta en la siguiente imagen,alguna persona me puede orientar para saber que error estoy comentiendo, que busque en otros lados y no encontré problema similar para poder guiarme.

[image: Error Streamlit, Pydeck]

```
Python 3.8.3
pydeck 0.5.0
streamlit 0.66.0



    import pandas as pd
import streamlit as st
import pydeck as pdk
import numpy as np
df = pd.DataFrame(
    np.random.randn(1000, 2) / [50, 50] + [37.76, -122.4],
    columns=['lat', 'lon'])

st.pydeck_chart(pdk.Deck(
     map_style='mapbox://styles/mapbox/light-v9',
     initial_view_state=pdk.ViewState(
         latitude=37.76,
         longitude=-122.4,
         zoom=11,
         pitch=50,
     ),
     layers=[
         pdk.Layer(
           'HexagonLayer',
            data=df,
            get_position='[lon, lat]',
            radius=200,
            elevation_scale=4,
            elevation_range=[0, 1000],
            pickable=True,
            extruded=True,
         ),
         pdk.Layer(
             'ScatterplotLayer',
             data=df,
             get_position='[lon, lat]',
             get_color='[200, 30, 0, 160]',
             get_radius=200,
         ),
     ],
 ))
```

Comment: Por favor cambia el código y la traza de error a fomato código, esto ayudará a su visibilidad y a que se pueda copiar y pegar para replicar el problema.

Answer (score -1):

Con la versión actual ese problema no me sale, no obstante chequea la indentación de la línea de código "import pandas as pd"